# Windows Update not working in the Windows 8 Add Printer dialog

Tags: windows-8, printer, windows-update, control-panel, lpt

I am trying to add a legacy LPT EPSON printer to my Windows 8 system, but it isn't listed in the base list in the Add Printer dialog (the one which opens when I choose to add the printer manually).

The problem is, when I click the **Windows Update** button, it opens a new window saying it's updating the printer list, but after ~15 minutes it times out saying it cannot access the server.

Internet is obviously working, and this is not a temporary issue (I tried it several times over the last couple of days).

[This thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/the-windows-update-button-in-the-add-printer/50129c93-6fee-4c41-98dc-d8ee71605f35) describes a similar problem in Windows 7, but the proposed solution says it will result in me losing all Windows Update history, and I am not sure about other implications it might have.

Has anyone had similar problems before?

**[Update]**

Additionally, the printer is listed as compatible on this [Windows Compatibility Center page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Name=Epson%20LQ-570%2b%20Printer&vendor=Epson&ModelOrVersion=C107001&Type=Hardware&TempOsid=Windows%208), and the page directs me to this [Microsoft Update Catalog page](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=762A3B25-15F4-40C1-8D66-4D8BAA184BD8), but I don't have a clue how to download the "update".

If anyone knows how to use the Catalog, it might solve my problem.

Comment: Do you run into issues when you use Windows Update for regular updates as opposed to the printer specifically?  If so, you might just use a workaround, and try and find a driver direct from Epson, rather than via Windows Update . . .

Comment: @ernie: no, Windows Update is working properly, and the [Epson page for that printer](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?oid=14305&BV_UseBVCookie=yes&infoType=Downloads&platform=OSF_W_VISTA-64) says that OS should already include these drivers. However, Windows 8 does not include them by default and should download them when I click on the Windows Update button inside the mentioned dialog.

Comment: How about using the MS update page via IE? (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Name=Epson%20LQ-570%2B%20Printer&vendor=Epson&ModelOrVersion=C107001&Type=Hardware&TempOsid=Windows%208)

Comment: @ernie: can you elaborate that a bit more? I am not sure how to use that Compatibility Center at all. Windows Update itself does not offer this as an update because it's an LPT printer (so there's no plug-and-play, auto discovery and other USB stuff). When I click the `Free download required` button on the page you mentioned it takes me to the [Microsoft Update Catalog page](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=762A3B25-15F4-40C1-8D66-4D8BAA184BD8) for that printer, but I don't know what I am supposed to do next?

Comment: @ernie: Oh crap, I am an idiot. There is a Download button available when I open the basket, and it works. Feel free to add it as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the built in Windows Update isn't working, you might try using the [Microsoft Compatibility Center link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Name=Epson%20LQ-570%2B%20Printer&vendor=Epson&ModelOrVersion=C107001&Type=Hardware&TempOsid=Windows%208).

You'll need IE, and you'll need to accept the Windows Update control or whatever it is.  At that point, you should see driver, which you can add to your basket.  After adding it, you can "view basket", and there'll be a download link in the upper right.